# Field name changes when I add a number

Tags: custom-list, column, internal-name

I use the shortest words possible when creating fields in a custom list.  I go back and rename it sometimes, but the URL retains the shorter name.

I have created a list, and have fields IS1 thru IS10. If I name the column I or IS, the internal field name matches, but when I add the number, it changes the I.

This is what I see for IS5:  Field=%5Fx0049%5FS5

I also created a field for I and IS for comparison:

I:  Field=I

IS: Field=IS

Can anyone explain why it would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure as to the why but I was able to duplicate your issue. A [similar thing](https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/sharepoint-column-names-internal-name-mappings-for-non-alphabet/) happens when you name a Field names with special characters. "For e.g. trying to create field `Emp Name` gives internal name as `Emp_x0020_Name`." Whatever the reason, it appears to be deliberate and possibly a security measure.

`Field Name  Internal Name
AA          AA
A5          %5Fx0041%5F5
AA5         %5Fx0041%5FA5
AAA5        %5Fx0041%5FAA5
AAAA5       AAAA5
II          II
I5          %5Fx0049%5F5
II5         %5Fx0049%5FI5
III5        %5Fx0049%5FII5
IIII5       IIII5`